# IBM MobileFirst Adapter based authentication in hybrid apps. Server sends UserIdentity object to client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Sample taken from here:
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/AdapterBasedAuth

mfp -v: 7.1.0.00.20151219-1541

When authentication succedes I get this response
[image]

As you can see server sends UserIdentity object to client.

My UserIdentity object stores additional ID keys that I get from backend and use to access backend through adapters. When WL server recognizes user, I can get those keys from UserIdentity (WL.Server.getActiveUser), and go to backend for data. I need those keys to stay on WL server.

How can I stop server sending UserIdentity object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got PMR response to this problem.

> The behaviour described in the PMR is the expected one.
>   The only way to avoid this is not saving the private data in the UserIdentity properties. The UserIdentity is meant to be shared between client and server.
>
> Alternatively, you can save the sensitive data in a database using the clientId variable. You can find an example on how to do so in the Two-Step adapter authentication tutorial.
>
> You can open a feature request but notice that this behaviour is by design.

So the question is closed